# continuous Intent listener android

Tags: android, android-intent, chat, continuous

I want to create an app that will print the strings that I send to from one activity to other.
Both activities are running simultaneously.
I want that i must be able to send string data anytime. And the other activity should print it.
like a chat application.

Comment: Use [Custom BroadCastReceiver](https://www.google.com/search?q=custom+broadcastreceiver+example).

Comment: @VenomVendor: thnx. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

In the same app 2 activities at the same time? I think you should consider Fragments. It is not possible to have 2 activities at the same time

Comment: what about TAB ACTIVITIES ? one base activity is also running and the tab activity is also running.

Comment: Ok, maybe you're right. I never used them actually. I would go with fragments anyway. And I would use the parent activity to allow communication with different ones.

Comment: No problem. This was only my point of you. Maybe you are write but considering I never used TabActivities I don't wanna give you wrong tips.